# Solving a first order differential equation in terms of Lambert W-function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, lambert-w

I am having great difficulty solving the following equation

$$\  \frac{ax}{(bx^2 + c)} = \frac{dx}{dt}  $$

I have re-edited the question. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what C is here?

Comment: C is just a constant, not from integration. Can call it "A"

Comment: if that makes any sense at all

Comment: Then why is this a differential equation, if there is only one variable... (if that makes any sense at all)

Comment: I am sorry about that. This actually comes from a differential equation, and the C would contain some integration constants. That's why I was trying to make sure I made sense, because my knowledge is admittedly limited. I will edit with the proper initial equation

Answer (score 5):

**This was for the first edit of the post.**

Welcome to the world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

The solution of equation $$\ x^2 + \log(x) - c = 0$$ is given by 
$$x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{W\left(2 e^{2 c}\right)}}{\sqrt{2}}$$ but only the positive root must be kept because of $\log(x).

The Wikipedia page gives series espansions fot he evaluation of $W(.)$.

If you cannot use Lambert function, think that you are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=x^2 + \log(x) - c$$ $$f'(x)=2x+\frac 1x$$  The first derivative does not cancel in the real domain and it is always positive; so, only one root that you could find numerically using any method (secant, Newton, ...). For starting,  you could start iterating using $x_0=\sqrt c$.

Suppose $c=0.01$. Newton iterations would then  be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.1000000000 \\
 1 & 0.3257436366 \\
 2 & 0.6013225902 \\
 3 & 0.6561217076 \\
 4 & 0.6564436996 \\
 5 & 0.6564437054
\end{array}
\right)$$
**For the new version of the post.**

Considering the differential equation
$$  \frac{ax}{(bx^2 + c)} = \frac{dx}{dt}\implies \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{b x}{a}+\frac{c}{a x}$$ we then have $$t+K=\frac{b x^2}{2 a}+\frac{c \log (x)}{a}$$ which would then lead to 
$$x^2=\frac{c }{b}W\left(\frac{b }{c}e^{\frac{2 a (K+t)}{c}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please provide for me an intermediate step? Regardless, thank you for your efforts and time.

Comment: Hmm this is very interesting, but in my limited knowledge, I am unsure if this is the direction I need to take this. I re-edited my question above. The initial equation you mentioned (x^2 + log(x) + C) = 0, was meant to solve for x(t) = ? . the solution you gave me using the Lambert function is correct. The problem is that I am not realizing how you got there, I will spend the next few days pouring over this question. For the second case, are you still setting the initial function equal to zero?

Comment: think i am beginning to see that you are finding the value of W(y) using the root finding algorithm

Comment: Your reply has been extremely helpful and insightful. Thank you. I will take a very through look at this. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your response to the new version of the post, is it possible to use newton's method instead of the W function. Thank you

Comment: @bsmith144. For sure ! If, for any reason, you cannot use Lambert function, Newton method is a very simple way to get the solution for solving for finding the zero of  $$f(x)=\frac{b x^2}{2 a}+\frac{c \log (x)}{a}-(t+K)$$

Comment: I am going to make a new thread to show my work thus far, I have having great difficulty obtaining the results you have above on my own.

Answer (score 2):

For the equation
$$\frac{ax}{(bx^2 + c)} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$
it can be seen that
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{a}{2 b} \, \frac{2 b x}{b x^{2} + c} = \frac{a}{2 b} \, \frac{d}{dt} \, \ln(b x^{2} + c )
\end{align}
which yields 
$$x(t) = \frac{a}{2 b} \, \ln(b x^{2} + c) + c_{0}.$$
Solving for $x(t)$ requires much struggle to obtain
$$x^{2}(t) = \frac{c}{b} \, W\left(\frac{b}{c} \, e^{\frac{2 \, a}{c} \, (t + p_{0})} \right),$$
where $p_{0}$ is a constant, and $W(x)$ is the Lambert w-function.

For verification use:
$$\frac{dW}{d z} = \frac{W(z)}{z \, (1 + W(z))}$$
for which
\begin{align}
2 \, x \, \frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{c}{b} \, \frac{b}{c} \, \frac{2 a}{c} \, e^{\frac{2 \, a}{c} \, (t + p_{0})} \, W'(\cdot) \\
&= \frac{2 a}{c} \, e^{\frac{2 \, a}{c} \, (t + p_{0})} \, \frac{W(\cdot)}{\frac{b}{c} \, e^{\frac{2 \, a}{c} \, (t + p_{0})} \, (1 + W(\cdot))} \\
&= \frac{2 a}{b} \, \frac{W(\cdot)}{1 + W(\cdot)} \\
&= \frac{2 a}{b} \, \frac{\frac{b}{c} \, x^{2}}{1 + \frac{b}{c} \, x^{2}} \\
&= \frac{2 a \, x^{2}}{b \, x^2 + c} \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{a \, x}{b \, x^{2} + c}.
\end{align}
This is the first order differential equation that was given.

Comment: Thank you Leucippus. Going to the section where you say "Solving for x(t) requires much struggle to obtain" --> don't you have an expression for x(t) in the previous segment?

Comment: Oh I see, never mind. Can you please share some insight into the steps which you define as a struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that $$\ln(x)=y \implies x=e^y$$
So I think what you are asking is solved using rearrangement and then using the above property. There is no differential equation here.

Comment: I am going to re-edit with the initial differential equation. Thank you for your reply