# Solving a first order differential equation in terms of Lambert W-function Continued:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lambert-w

I have had some excellent answers in response to a previous question here:

[Solving a first order differential equation in terms of Lambert W-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497559/solving-a-first-order-differential-equation-in-terms-of-lambert-w-function)

However I would like to show my work some more since I am still stuck, and terribly lost, in hopes for some further guidance. Thank you all.

So I was left with an equation of the following form:

$$ t + K = \frac{bx^2}{2a} + \frac{c\ln(x)}{a}   $$

Multiplying through by $$ \frac{2a}{c}$$
Gives

$$ \frac{2a(t + K)}{c} = \frac{b}{c} x^2 + 2\ln(x)   $$

Following by:

$$ exp(\frac{2a(t + K)}{c}) = x^2 exp(bx^2/c)   $$

It is at this point here I am stuck. I actually am not 100 percent sure the final step I made is valid. However I belive here that the function is now in the form:  $$ y = x exp(x) $$ Which is the form needed to use the Lambert function $$ W(y) = x $$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$exp(\frac{2a(t + K)}{c}) = x^2 exp(bx^2/c)$$
multiply by $b/c$ and let $y = (b/c) \, x^{2}$ for
$$\frac{b}{c} \, exp(\frac{2a(t + K)}{c}) = y exp(y).$$
Now, use the Lambert W-function to obtain, $y = z \, e^{z} \to z = W(y)$,
$$y = W\left(\frac{b}{c} \, exp(\frac{2a(t + K)}{c})\right)$$
and since $y = (b/c) \, x^{2}$ then
$$x^{2} = \frac{c}{b} \, W\left(\frac{b}{c} \, exp(\frac{2a(t + K)}{c})\right).$$

Comment: Wow!!! excellent! Thank you, Leucippus, thank you very much!!

Comment: If I were to express the Lambert-W function as a series, such as is described on the Wikipedia page, would the "z" in the series: W(z) = z - z*z + 1.5*z*z*z + .....  etc,  be the function argument above?